# Распознавание переменной одного блока переменного другого блока

Tags: c#

Как в C# сделать, чтобы один блок, распознавал переменную другого блока? Возможно ли такое?

Comment: В начале тела класса пишем: 
static [тип] [переменная];
И она будет доступна во всех методах данного класса.
А если нужен доступ во всех классах, то пишем:
public [тип] [переменная];

Comment: @Mikola Если следовать вашей логике, то у вас `static` получился антонимом `public` :)

Comment: @Mikola а почему static? И причем тут ваш ответ к данному вопросу?

Comment: @Mikola прав, т.к и я слышал про такое свойство static. Просто в тот момент как-то не пришло в голову.

Comment: @navi1893 Правда слышали? Расскажите тогда, пожалуйста, что же вы имели ввиду под **разными блоками.**

Comment: @navi1893 static - свойство?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы про переменные, локальные для `{ ... }` блоков, то нет, нельзя.